# How to unparse an ast tree in python using asttokens?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to unparse an AST tree in python back to source code after making some changes on that code, but formatting such as blank lines are lost. How can I preserve formatting when calling ast.unparse()?
I know ast.unparse() itself cannot recover formatting options, but is there a way to do this using a module like asttokens?

```
import ast
from asttokens import ASTTokens

# 1. Create a code string
code_str = """
print('1')

print('2')
"""


tree = ast.parse(code_str)

# modifications...

new_code_str = ast.unparse(tree)

# Print the original and modified code strings
print("Original code: ", code_str)
print("Modified code: ", new_code_str)
```

I want the modified code to preserve newlines, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that `ast.unparse` doesn't produce the original whitespace, it's that the original whitespace isn't in the AST *at all*.

You need a *concrete* syntax tree (CST) instead. Here's an example using [libcst](https://pypi.org/project/libcst/).

```
>>> code_str = """
... print('1')
...
... print('2')
... """
>>> cst = libcst.parse_module(code_str)
>>> print(cst.code)

print('1')

print('2')

>>> assert cst.code == code_str
```

You can print the CST itself to see how the actual source code is represented. Here's a small sample.

```
>>> print(str(cst)[:500])
Module(
    body=[
        SimpleStatementLine(
            body=[
                Expr(
                    value=Call(
                        func=Name(
                            value='print',
                            lpar=[],
                            rpar=[],
                        ),
                        args=[
                            Arg(
                                value=SimpleString(
                                    value="'1'",
```

Comment: Yes, I was aware that ASTs dont retain such information. Thank you, a CST might work. I'll check if it allows me to transform the tree as desired